# Why input impedence is important factor for amplifiers

Tags: transistors, amplifier, analog, bjt

What I know about amplifiers is that its main objective is to amplify small ac signals and how much signal can be amplified is  known by calculating open circuit output voltage  (without load) or more accurately by calculating overall voltage across load  and higher the value of overall voltage gain higher will be amplification of ac signal .

But in all these things what I explained above has nothing to do with input impedence because Even if we increase input impedence  it causes decrease in voltage gain (for example CE with emitter resistance amplifier) and hence overall voltage will remain same .So that's why I don't understand how increasing input impedence is considered good ?although it adds nothing to amplification i.e overall output voltage remains same (compared to when input impedence is Less)  which is main purpose of amplifier .

I asked  almost similar question but I don't get much information from answer may be my question was not that well asked

[How input resistance related to better amplification in transistor circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/529805/how-input-resistance-related-to-better-amplification-in-transistor-circuit)

Comment: How good or useful would an oscilloscope be with an input impedance of a few kohm?

Comment: @Andy  I don't understand your question and how is it related to my question?

Comment: An o-scope uses a high input impedance so that it doesn't load the signal it is measuring. Some signals require that - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *But in all these things what I explained above has nothing to do with
> input impedence because Even if we increase input impedence it causes
> decrease in voltage gain (for example CE with emitter resistance
> amplifier) and hence overall voltage will remain same .So that's why I
> don't understand how increasing input impedence is considered good
> ?although it adds nothing to amplification i.e overall output voltage
> remains same (compared to when input impedence is Less) which is main
> purpose of amplifier .*

What you are missing here is why we use an emitter resistor. Yes, for sure it increases the input impedance and that is a good thing for some types of amplifier but, it is "bad" when amplifying signals from sensors that require an almost zero input impedance for best results. So, for a guitar amplifier you want the input impedance to be between 1 Mohm to 10 Mohm so that you don't attenuate higher frequencies and make the sound dull. For an accelerometer you want the input impedance to be near-zero so that you can convert charge to voltage using a charge amplifier. For an RF circuit, almost always you want maximum power transfer and you make the input (and output impedances) around 50 ohm.

So, going back to the common emitter, if you **don't use** an emitter resistor you get poor results and these include: -

- Heavy distortion on bigger signals
- Temperature related quiescent voltage drift
- Temperature related gain i.e. gain changes with temperature
- Poor frequency response
- and of course low input impedance.

So, adding an emitter resistor is something we must do and, if it lowers the gain then so be it; add another gain stage - in fact use an op-amp or other tech.

Comment: Thanks Andy ! addresses my all concerns , so basically there is no thumb of rule as such that input impedence should be high ,it all depends on what our desired output should be and what  input signal is and based on that we design our amplifier parameters?

Comment: Correct; some things want high impedance and some want low for best results.

Answer (score 1):

Input impedance of amplifier forms the lower arm of a potential divider with the source impedance of whatever is driving the amplifier.

The lower the amplifier's input impedance then the more the signal is attenuated before it even arrives at the amplifier.

Comment: But what if we let signal to attenuated at input side and then increase gain so that we get our desired output instead of increasing input impedence , in the end output matters isn't ?

Comment: True, you could compensate for a lower amplifier input impedance by increasing the gain  to achieve a certain overall required gain.

Comment: The idea that you can ignore a high impedance input and just offset the source attenuation with a larger gain factor is the worst way to look at it. While technically feasible, your amplified  signal would be very poor quality. Why reduce the source signal to only then amplify it afterwards? Think, the smaller the source signal the worse the SNR, the bigger the noise floor, the poorer the quality of the amplified signal.